# Updating existing excel book in npoi won't update existing formulas

Tags: excel, .net-core, npoi

I'm modifying an existing excel file using NPOI. When I edit an cell and give it a value using NPOI, it sets the value correctly. However, existing formulas in the spread sheet are not updated to reflect this new information. The seem to be shown as plain text. I have found that I can reset these values by going over all these fields and setting their content as the formula value.

How could I do this for the entire sheet all at once?

My code

```
        var embedded = "ProjectNamespace.pathToEmbeddedFile.xlsx";
        var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook;
        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(embedded);
        {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
        }
        
        var sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
        var row = sheet.GetRow(8);
        var cell = row.GetCell(10);
        cell.SetCellValue("test");

        // adding these lines will reset the cell formula
        cell = row.GetCell(11);
        cell.SetCellFormula(cell.ToString());
     
        // saving the file
        using (var file = File.Create("thanosDidNothingWrong.xlsx"))
        {
            workbook.Write(file);
        }
```

the excel contains the formula '=K9' on cell 'L9'.